# Why does Code Runner in VSCode not show the correct output in Terminal?

Tags: c++, vscode-code-runner, coderunner

I am following the first Lecture for installing c++ mingw compiler for vscode (Jenny's Lectures CS IT) and after installing the code runner extension, the result of the program should be printed to terminal, in this case, Hello world.

However, my result for the same thing is this: cd "c:\Users\jesss\OneDrive\Documents\C++" ; if ($?) { g++ setup.cpp -o setup } ; if ($?) { .\setup }

Why is this and how do I fix it to ensure this runs as expected?

TLDR: Pressed the run code button in vscode and expected Hello World.

Received cd "c:\Users\jesss\OneDrive\Documents\C++" ; if ($?) { g++ setup.cpp -o setup } ; if ($?) { .\setup }

Can confirm code runner run in terminal is checked in settings

Comment: It could be your antivirus or OneDrive or looking in a different tab of VSCode. I don't have it installed on my work PC so I can't test. With this said I urge you to follow the official VSCode MinGW instructions instead: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: Note that Code Runner is pretty simple. It's OK for very simple toy programs, but it falls down hard as complexity grows. Modifications are required as soon as you have multiple source files that need compiling.

Comment: If some purported "lecture" that's targeted for beginners tells them to diddle around with mingw and VSCode, that "lecture" needs to be shredded into tiny little pieces, and replaced with a more appropriate "lecture". MinGW requires some amount of technical expertise to properly install, since it is alien software that's ported to a foreign operating system. VSCode is designed for experienced developers and requires arcane configuration settings, expressed as convoluted JSON-formatted configuration files, to be set up. Neither tool is appropriate for beginners.

Comment: what people are trying to say is to install Microsoft visual studio (not VScode) and use it, it requires less tinkering and experience to reach a working simple app.

Comment: I recommend ignoring any lecture or course or book or tutorial that starts with instructions on how to install VSCode.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik do you have any recommendations for what and where I could look into to learn and develop understanding in c++ as a beginner?